# Roots of a degree $3$ polynomial with real coefficients.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $3$ with real coefficient.

Then  which of the following is possible $?$

$A. p(x)$ has no real root. WRONG.

$B.p(x)$ has exactly two real roots. WRONG AGAIN.

$C.p(1)=-1,p(2)=1,p(3)=11\ and\ p(4)=35.$

$D.i-1\ \ and\ \ i+1$ are roots of $p(x)$. 
 As these are NOT conjugates, so cannot be roots  of  the  same  polynomial  so  AGAIN WRONG .

So, that leaves  out  only  option  $C$. Now , what I was thinking was that , I could say only $C$  is  possible  because  I  had  ways  of  eliminating  the  rest . But  what if the  eliminations were not this easy , was  there  any  way  to  say  that , a  polynomial  of  degree  $3$  actually  exists  satisfying  what is given in  $C$ $?$ How can I actually  find  out  such  a  polynomial  $?$

Hope I could convey  my question  properly.

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: Please state the problem clearly. Is the problem asking which of a,b,c,d is correct?

Comment: See if you can solve for the polynomial with linear algebra. Also seems like you didn't write out the full question. Shouldn't there be some kind of "which of the following are possible?" thing written in the problem statement?

Comment: @anon : Yes . There is. I'll  edit .

Comment: For four points, one cannot always find a polynomial of degree *exactly* $3$.  But $\le 3$ follows from general considerations. A nice way to do it is Lagrange interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Option $B$ is quite ambiguous since double roots can exist.

Concerning $C$, write the polynomial as $$P(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$$ so $$P(1)=a+b+c+d=-1$$ $$P(2)=a+2 b+4 c+8 d=1$$ $$P(3)=a+3 b+9 c+27 d=11$$ $$P(4)=a+4 b+16 c+64 d=35$$ Solve for $a,b,c,d$ using the method of your choice.

Comment: I solved the  system of equations  and found values of $a,b,c,d.$  (Provided , I've not  miscalculated any step) . So , does that mean the equation is found and option $C$ is a possibility $?$

Comment: @user118494. If all coefficients exist, $C$ is then true.

Comment: @user118494. For sure, $d\neq 0$ is a requirement.

Comment: : No $d=3$ I got.

Comment: @user118494. So, I am afraid that you have a mistake; $d\neq 0$ but  $d\neq 3$ .

Comment: That's bad . I'll do it again. But can I ask you something $?$ If you know $d\neq 3$ then,I guess you must have worked it out and know what values $a,b,c,d$ take . Would you tell me what you've got $?$

Comment: You just face four simple linear equations for four unknowns. Please do it ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the analytical point of view ,by Weierstrass approximation theorem, given the four points, we can construct an interpolating polynomial (recall from the numerical analysis classes )of degree 3 which assumes the same value at the given points.

Answer (score 0):

A real polynomial of degree $\leq 3$ can be fit to *any* given real values at $3+1$ points.   The only thing requiring a calculation is to test that the $4$ given values are not fit by a polynomial of degree $2$ or lower. Since the points are at consecutive integer $x$ coordinates this exceptional case is easily tested by taking differences of the sequence.